# focus from JTable is not losting even after frame is dispoed in java?

Tags: java, swing

i have two frame. and there is a button  on frame 1st which opens 2nd frame.

note -- frame 1st is still open. when we open 2nd frame

and 2nd frame have textfields and table and button(update) to update the row. and when i click on row in table . then  all column value of that row go to their respective textfields.  but when i close the frame *after clicking on table row * and open the 2nd frame again from the frame 1st .   then that row is still selected and all the textfields are filled with that row value. and update button also don't work.

but when i close all frame and run the frame again it works fine

Comment: Probably your table or whole frame is a static variable. But without code we can only guess

Comment: So, you want to deselect the row at some point?

Comment: removing static worked

Comment: you can answer it.. so, i can approve

Comment: *"you can answer it.."* Tip: Add @Piro (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Okay @Andrew Thompson

Answer (score 1):

@pero

Removed static from frame and JTable. And it works.

Comment: Why not ***wait*** for **Piro** to make that an answer?

Comment: I was waiting... But you said add pero to your answer

Comment: Its ok. What Andrew meant was to add `@` in front of `Piro`. That way I will be notified you mentioned me. You can also (I think after 24 hours) accept own answer to indicate that you found the solution. In future it is helpfull to post [MCVE program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see where did your code go wrong or simulate error on our own machines.